# How Quarkus transactional works with reactive sql client

Tags: transactions, reactive-programming, quarkus

Currently i'm trying to build some simple prototype application with Quarkus (1.3.1). I'm trying to use a reactive approach with reactive database connection to PostgreSQL using https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients. Here I'm using kotlin and mutiny to simplify things a bit.

I have the following controller:

```kotlin
package me.invitation.infrastructure.rest

import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni
import me.invitation.application.service.InvitationService
import me.invitation.infrastructure.rest.api.InvitationDto
import me.invitation.infrastructure.rest.system.MicroserviceContentType
import org.eclipse.microprofile.context.ThreadContext
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.ws.rs.*
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response


@Path("/invitation")
class Resource @Inject constructor(
        private val invitationService: InvitationService,
        private val threadContext: ThreadContext) {


    @POST
    @Consumes(MicroserviceContentType.PUBLIC_RSC_JSON)
    fun postInvitation(invitation: InvitationDto): Uni<Response> {
        return Uni.createFrom()
                .completionStage(
                        threadContext.withContextCapture(
                                invitationService.sendInvite(invitation.email)))
                .map { Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED).build() }
    }

    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Resource::class.java)
    }
}
```

The **InvitationService** implementation is as follows:

```kotlin
package me.invitation.application.service

import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni
import me.invitation.application.registry.InvitationRegistry
import me.invitation.application.service.mail.MailService
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty
import org.eclipse.microprofile.context.ManagedExecutor
import org.eclipse.microprofile.context.ThreadContext
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
import java.security.SecureRandom
import java.time.Duration
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
import java.util.function.Supplier
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.transaction.Transactional

@ApplicationScoped
class ExternalRegistryInvitationService @Inject constructor(
        private val invitationRepository: InvitationRegistry,
        private val mailService: MailService,
        private val threadContext: ThreadContext,
        private val managedExecutor: ManagedExecutor,
        @ConfigProperty(name ="invitation.expiration-ttl-seconds") private val invitationTTLSeconds: Long
) : InvitationService {

    @Transactional
    override fun sendInvite(email: String): CompletableFuture<Unit> {
        return Uni.createFrom()
                  .completionStage(threadContext.withContextCapture(invitationRepository.save(id, email)))
                  .flatMap {wasSaved ->
                                if(wasSaved) {
                                   Uni.createFrom().completionStage(threadContext.withContextCapture(mailService.sendInvitationEmail(email)))
                                } else {
                                    throw InvitationAlreadyPresentException()
                                }
                            }.subscribeAsCompletionStage()
    }
}
```

Here I'm trying to save a record in database and after that send an email

**InvitationRegistry** implementation is as follows:

```kotlin
package me.invitation.infrastructure.db

import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni
import io.vertx.mutiny.pgclient.PgPool
import io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.Tuple
import me.invitation.application.registry.InvitationRegistry
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.transaction.Transactional

@ApplicationScoped
class PostgresInvitationRegistry @Inject constructor(private val client: PgPool) : InvitationRegistry {

    private final val insertQuery = "INSERT INTO invitation(id, email, aud_ts_created, aud_ts_last_modified) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id"

    @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.MANDATORY)
    override fun save(id: String, email: String): CompletableFuture<Boolean> {
        return client
                .preparedQuery(insertQuery, Tuple.of(id, email, LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now()))
                .flatMap { result -> Uni.createFrom().item(result.rowCount() > 0) }
                .subscribeAsCompletionStage()
    }
}
```

MailService implementation is irrelevant because everything it does is throwing RuntimeException.

Here I'm expecting that top-level transaction to rollback. Because **MailService.sendInvitationEmail** is throwing an exception. But that's not the case. Even in case of exception the record is persisted. I have read this guide https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction#reactive-extensions and https://quarkus.io/guides/context-propagation#usage-example-for-completionstage and I thought that declarative transactions works well with reactive sql in Quarkus.

I think that there is an **autocommit** setting for reactive connection which is set to true. But didn't find anything related to autocommit, neither in docs, nor in the sources of quarkus and its extensions. Suprisingly, there is even no autocommit setting even for quarkus main jdbc pool = agroal!

Myabe someone knows how to make declarative transactions work with reactive sql client in Quarkus

Comment: One note is PgPool.preparedQuery is forcibly use vertx eventloop thread pool instead of  quarkus managed thread pool. I don't know wheather it is a bug or not. But in that case context propagation using ThreadContext is not working. Any subsequent action after PgPool.preparedQuery is run on vertx pool with no thread context.

Comment: Some debugging shows that **@Transactional** itself is working as expected i.e. it calls rollback after exception is thrown in **MailService**. The problem is that reactive sql client is completely unaware of that transaction. It acquires it's own connection to db and sucessfully autocommits it.

Comment: Did you find how to make transactions work with reactive sql client?

Comment: No. Currently we have to stick with imperative transactions